# How to iterate over instances of defined types in Puppet

Tags: types, resources, scope, puppet, defined

I want to iterate over all instances of defined types (ex. Apache::Vhost). However this loop only list my resources under the scope.

```
<% scope.catalog.vertices.each do |resource| -%>
<%# if resource.type == "Apache::Vhost" -%>
#Include <%= resource.title %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that as this introduces parse-order dependencies. I don't think there are robust ways to do that.

Comment: I have a dependency for that

    Class['Apache::Params'] -> Apache::Vhost <| |>

Comment: Inter resource dependencies are resolved in the end, while your template will be resolve in the middle of catalog compilation. This means that if you define an `apache::vhost` "after" (where after is undefined, as you have no parse order garantees AFAIK) you defined your template, it will not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Walking the catalog durig at compile time ("catalog building") is a Bad Idea.

If you really want this functionality, think about moving the iteration code to a [custom provider](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/provider_development.html) that will generate the file content akin to what your master side template tries at the moment.

At the sync stage, you can safely access the complete catalog via `self.resource.catalog`.