# How to build a file based on defined-type instances in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I want my Puppet class to create a file resource with contents based on all instances of a particular defined type.  I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054661/how-to-iterate-over-instances-of-defined-types-in-puppet) with the idea of iterating over the instances to build the file, but apparently it's a "Bad Idea" per the one answer currently there.

Some background: I am building a `monitor_service` class in Puppet to deploy a custom monitoring application.  The application reads a config file that tells it what to monitor, one item per line, along the lines of

```
ITEM: /var/things/thing-one (123)
ITEM: /var/things/thing-two (456)
```

I am also writing a defined type that deploys instances of the monitored items:

```
define my_thing::monitored_thing ( $port ) {
  file { "/var/things/$name":
     ...
  }
}
```

On a given node, I set up several `monitored_thing`s like

```
my_thing::monitored_thing { "thing-one":
  port => 123
}
my_thing::monitored_thing { "thing-two":
  port => 456
}
```

What's the "right" Puppet idiom for building the monitoring service config file?  I would prefer for this to work in such a way that the `monitor_service` class doesn't have to be told which `monitored_thing` instances it is watching -- just creating a `monitored_thing` instance should cause it to be added to the config file automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to modify/declare only part of a file within multiple defined types:

1. Use [`puppetlabs-stdlib`](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib)'s `file_line`. This lets you specify that a file should contain a specific line. Best when you do not care about the other file contents and just want to make sure a line is present or absent.
2. Use [`puppetlabs-concat`](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/concat) if you want to make sure that the final file only includes the fragments that you are specifying or the order of the fragments matters.
3. Use the [`augeas` type](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#augeas) if you need to edit/add configuration to a file with a more complicated structure, like xml, apache configurations, etc.

Comment: These are fantastic leads, thanks for the pointers!  I'll stop by here again when I've figured out what I'm doing.

Comment: I think `file_line` is going to work for my use case, but it would be nice if when defining the line content, I could tell "which" instance this is.  That is, something like `my_thing::monitored_thing.count` which would tell me how many instances of this defined type have been created, at the time the line is evaluated.  I know that's "parse-order dependent", which is A Bad Thing, but in this case it would help me out.  Is it impossible?

Comment: I'm testing `file_line` but I can't seem to make it work.  I have a simple entry that looks like `file_line { "test": path=> '/opt/monitor/README', line => 'This is extra text' }` (note that the README file is not controlled by Puppet!) and nothing happens.  I have also tried pointing it at a file that *is* controlled by my module; no change.

Comment: That was a [false alarm](http://serverfault.com/questions/411245/puppetlabs-file-line-type-not-working), though Puppet *definitely* should not just act like everything is fine when the catalog references a plugin that the client does not have.  Is that fixed in later Puppet versions?  (I'm stuck with 2.7.something)

Comment: @Coderer With later versions of puppet I am pretty sure you will get an error if you try to use a type that you do not have the module for. Were you able to get it to work? You need to install the stdlib module on the puppetmaster and then make sure that pluginsync is enabled.

Comment: With `pluginsync`, everything seems to be working.  I am going to look into updating Puppet, but I'd like to avoid having to work outside of the (admittedly ancient) stuff CentOS gives us natively unless it's really important.